# Does SharePoint 2010 offer document level encryption?

Tags: sharepoint, encryption, sharepoint-2010, document-management

I can't seem to find any clear answer via Google or Microsoft's site, but I could be completely missing it. Aside from encrypting the content database using Transparent Data Encryption, what are some other recommended ways of approaching this? Does the Rights Management Services assist in this? If TDE is used on the database, will that inhibit indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no document level encryption in SharePoint 2010.
I don't know whether the TDE will affect your index or not. But it's transperant to SharePoint.
RMS is for Office documents (like Word) and relies on AD to authenticate reader's permissions. You can check demos on Microsoft's site for more details on how it works, http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/ad-rms-demos.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Our company is looking at another product for encrypting documents in SharePoint from a place called Cryptzone. Not sure if anyone has used it, but seems promising on paper.
We need something for a small group of users that'll protect a small group of files.

From what I see TDE with SQL is only available in the Enterprise product and also encrypts the system tables that means other DBs on that instance must also be encrypted.